# Synchronisation in android

Tags: android, exception, media-player

I am using media player to play the sound in the pacman game. whenever it plays the sound then it will give following error.

**Unable to resync. Signalling end of stream**

I want to ask why this type of error comes. Is there any memory problem regarding this and how can i solve this problem. when i do volume up or down then device is restarted whenever sound is played i don't know why.

Comment: Some source code would be good, as would clarification as to whether the sound successfully plays just once, or never.

Comment: sounds plays successfully for 4-5 minutes after that it stops the sound.